# Add private file (that are not pushed) with a commit, possible?

Tags: git

I've this question because it would be really helpful in such cases :
I'm currently working on an open-source program, and I'd like to keep the git repo clean, containing only source and build related files. However, beside that, I wrote some scripts that are relevant only for me but quite linked with the commit or the branch I'm working on.

Is there a possibility for having these files saved with the commit but not pushed on the remote repo ?

Comment: Put your scripts in a submodule repo that you don't push... That way, a specific commit in your main repo can be tied to a specific version of your scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway you're working in your separate repo and branch. So you may commit your utility files along with corresponding chahges. When you prepare a commit for pull request, just make a separate release branch, checkout it and remove these files in the next commit. Your development branch will still have these files in older commits.

when a feature is ready:
create a branch and checkout into it

```
git checkout -b pull_request
git rm <all utility files>
git commit -am'removed utility files'
```

you also can make it a single commit, to keep the history tidy. After the previous commands:

```
git reset --soft <sha1 where I forked this branch>
git commit -am'implemented feature X'
```

Now your branch pull_request contains all changes of the last commit and NOT contain your utility files in any of the mid-development commits.

Answer (score 0):

Not easily, if you want not to push a file, it cannot be in the commit (a branch is just pointer to a commit). The commit hash is created among other from the file tree it contains, so omitting a file will change the hash and break synchronization with the remote repo.

You can have these files in a different repo and use a script to switch branches on both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

How about you have them in your working tree as untracked changes!
Add them to .git/info/exclude file so that they don't show up in status.

You never commit them and by that extension you never push them!
You may however choose to maintain a separate copy of your scripts (a git repo in itself probably), so that you don't by mistake delete them from your worktree. (Git will never touch them, if they are untracked).

Comment: I know, but the goal is to link them to the commit, but only on local computer (so I think the best is to have a hook that call a script that manage them (like doing the same commit tree in another repo and copy past the files

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to have a private github folder (not a pretty solution).